# Difference when comparing int and string having dynamic, object and int/string as parameter?

Tags: c#, string, object, dynamic, compare

I tried to compare two int values and two string values using equals operator ' == '. I used 3 functions which have as input parameter type dynamic, object and int/string. When I compare using a string parameter, it seems that in all 3 cases using the ' == ' operator returns the correct answer. When using an int type, in the case of object input type parameter, it returns false even if the 2 int values are equal. I know that ' == ' operator, in case of objects, it compares if the 2 object have the same reference in memory, so this could explain why I receive false. But I don't understand why in case of string type it works just fine.

Code:

```cs
public static bool CompareD(dynamic a, dynamic b)
{
    return a == b;
}

public static bool CompareO(object a, object b)
{
    return a == b;
}

public static bool CompareS(int a, int b)
{
    return a == b;
}
```

I was expecting that when I use string, in the case of object type input parameter to receive false even if those 2 strings are equal, as in case of int, but I receive the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because Strings are immutable. The code that's making this happen is in the String class. It looks like this:

```
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
    return string.Equals(a, b);
}
```

So any "==" comparisons are going to check equality rather than references on Strings.